# PHP,Laravel 8 backend

Tags: php, authentication, authorization, backend, laravel-8

I am building backend of an "event website" in php,laravel 8 and there are two things I am supposed to do : 1)tokenization of the users 2)authorize users i.e. separate them as normal users vs admin only who can add the event

Comment: what is your question? it's not clear.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

---

## Tokenization:

#### in few steps

```sh
composer require laravel/passport
```

```sh
php artisan migrate
```

in users model
import the the package's trait

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens
```

```sh
php artisan passport:install
```

```
public function login($request) {
        $user = User::whereEmail($request->email)->first();
        if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
            $token = $user->createToken('Laravel Password Grant Client')->accessToken;
            return response(["message" => "Success", "token" => $token]);
        } 
        return response(["message" => "Incorrect Credentials"]);
    }
```

#### and token is ready

---

## Authorization:

as for authorization there is a wonderful permissions package from spatie library that has the feature ready with step-by-step tutorial

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction

#### Good Luck

---